# Using MATLAB Map Containers without converting to cell arrays first

Tags: matlab

Say I have the following two arrays:

```
keys   = uint32([1:100])';
values = uint32([100:-1:1])';
```

I can define a map container as follows:

```
newMap = containers.Map(keys,values);

newMap = 
  containers.Map handle
  Package: containers

  Properties:
        Count: 100
      KeyType: 'uint32'
    ValueType: 'uint32'
  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

The type is the same for keys and values, `uint32`.

However, if I want to use the container to map a new array:

```
other_keys = uint32([5 9 10]);
```

I read in the documentation I have to convert `other_keys` to a cell array first:

```
>> newMap(other_keys)
Error using containers.Map/subsref
Specified key type does not match the type expected
for this container.
```

or:

```
values(newMap, other_keys);

Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of
class 'containers.Map'.
```

The only way to make it work is with:

```
values(newMap, num2cell(other_keys));
```

which can take a long **time** and a lot of **memory**! For example, if I have 100 million numbers, I get:

```
tic
my_uint32_array = uint32(1:100000000)
my_cell_array   = num2cell(my_uint32_array);
toc

Elapsed time is 27.956496 seconds.
```

where:

- `my_uint32_array` is `381.5 MB` in size
- `my_cell array` is `10.8GB` in size (**100x** times bigger!, even though this is just a temporal variable, since I am **only** interested in mapping my values after all)

Considering that I can **create** Map containers without having to convert to cell arrays first, is there a way to use them without having to convert my keys to cell arrays first?

Answer (score 2):

Wait, I don't get it. The code

```
values(newMap, num2cell(other_keys));
```

which is equivalent to

```
newMap.values(num2cell(other_keys));
```

will only work if your keys are an array of `1:N`. 
Otherwise, you are not taking the correct values. But if the keys are an array of `1:N`, you should not use `Map`. You can simply define an array of `uint32`.

In case you meant that you want to do something like this:

```
for key=other_keys
   vals(end+1) = newMap(key);
end
```

you can also try to do the following vectorization:

```
vals = arrayfun( @(x)(newMap(x)),other_keys);
```

Though I am not sure it will work faster.